# Golang pass arguments to gorilla router

Tags: mysql, go

So I have two files. In one I have initialize a gorilla router, and register handlers. In the other I define the handlers. The handlers are supposed to query a MYSQL database. Routes.go looks like this -

```
    package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "fmt"
)

type Route struct {
    Name string
    Method string
    Pattern string
    HandlerFunc http.HandlerFunc
}

type Routes[]Route

func NewRouter() *mux.Router {
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "psanker:123@/education_data")
    err = db.Ping()

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to prepare connection to database")
        log.Fatal("Error:", err.Error())
    }

    defer db.Close()

    router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    for _, route := range routes {
        router.
            Methods(route.Method).
            Path(route.Pattern).
            Name(route.Name).
            Handler(route.HandlerFunc)
    }
    return router
}

var routes = Routes{
    Route {
        "Index",
        "GET",
        "/",
        Index,
    },
    Route {
        "getDistrict",
        "GET",
        "/district/{districtId}",
        getDistrict,
        DBConn &db,
    },
    Route {
        "getDistricts",
        "GET",
        "/districts",
        getDistricts,
    },
}
```

My handlers.go file looks like this -

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "encoding/json"
)

func Index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "WELCOME!")
}

func getDistrict(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    districtId := vars["districtId"]
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "District id : ", districtId)
}

func getDistricts(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * from districts")
    check(err)
    var district District
    for rows.Next() {
        var id int64
        test := "hey"
        district = District{Id: id, Activities: test}
    }

    if err := json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(district); err != nil {
        check(err)
    }
}
```

I want to use one database connection for all of my handlers, how do I achieve this?

Comment: Hi I'd like to answer your question however you have some problems with your code right now that make me unsure about how to do so. If you're OK holding this connection open all you really want is to define it your main package and set it up prior to turning on the routes. Anyway, in that composite literal declaration of `routes` you use `db` even though it's not in scope and (even if it were) there is no field to assign it to in the `Route` instance. If you correct that enough for me to understand your intent then I can more easily put forward a solution.

Comment: You could look at gorilla context for passing extra data around http requests. http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/context

Answer (score 2):

Go's `sql.DB` type represents a connection pool and not a single connection. It is recommended that you create a pool on program initialization and either:

1. Create a global pool and just use it (the pool is safe for concurrent access)

   ```
   var db *sql.DB

   func main() {
   var err error
   db, err = sql.Open("connection string here")
   if err != nil {
       // handle it
   }

   // Rest of program/router/etc
   }

   func MyHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   err := db.Query("...")
   if err != nil {
        // handle it
       }

       // Rest of handler
   }
   ```
2. Create custom handler functions that satisfy `http.Handler` and accept the pool or a struct containing the pool as an additional argument. I wrote about that here: https://elithrar.github.io/article/custom-handlers-avoiding-globals/

(I would provide another example but I'm on mobile; excuse the poor indentation)

Also look at [sqlx](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx) to simplify your query into/from struct handling.

Answer (score 1):

Elithar's answer is the standard way of achieving this. If you want to inject a db connection in every handler, this is one way to solve it. You define your own handler and convert it back to what the router expects. Here is the example, I assume, that Elithar wanted to give.

```
func main() {
    http.HandlerFunc(myDbHandler(Index, db))
}

type dbHandler func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, db *sql.DB)

func myDbHandler(handler dbHandler, db *sql.DB) func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        handler(w, r, db)
    }
}

func Index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, db *sql.DB) {
    // handler code goes here
}
```